# Dragon Quest VIII ending

Tags: dragon-quest-viii

I finally finished Dragon Quest VIII last night. One question I have though is about right at the end. After the credits the final thing you see is some sort of symbol on a stone plinth that glows red. I think it is where you fought Rhapthrone and had to escape the area (so when he is a little blob not  the big chunky guy in the sky).

What is the significance of this glowing stone? Is it related to the post-game adventure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct - the gem that glows at the end of the credits is the beginning of the post-game content. Once you track it down and interact with it, you're teleported to the secret dungeon.

It's been a while since I played DQ8 so I can't remember how to get there exactly, but [this question on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/583527-dragon-quest-viii-journey-of-the-cursed-king/answers?qid=101961) seems to outline it:

> Continue the game and go to Argonia, use your godbird soulstone and fly past the tent, then fly to the 2-way path and onto the mountaintop that's accessible by foot and boat. Land on the building and speak to the gem,you will be transported into a cave.

Comment: I've really enjoyed the game. I'm very tempted to continue to do this, but do you know how many hours roughly it will take?

Comment: @VictorySaber I can't say, sadly - I messed around in it for an hour or so but never took it on seriously.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple parts to the post-game.  The first part, which is necessary to gain some additional "story" related content, and which I *highly* recommend doing, is likely to only take you a few hours to complete (five or less I'd guess).  There's further optional content after that, but which doesn't really have anything to do with the story, that may take another 20+ hours depending on leveling.

Comment: So where do I start? Going to Argonia as BiscuitBaker said?